# Delete user with Vue.js and Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I cant remove account from firebase in vue.js. I used firebase docs.
Here is button to delete:

```
<template>
[...]
      <div class="text-center">
        <button type="button" class="btn text-white my-4" @click="$emit('deleteUser')">Delete account</button>
      </div>
[...]
</template>
```

Here is method:

```
<script>
[...]
import firebase from "firebase"
import {router} from '../main'

export default {
    [...]
  },
  methods: {
    [...]
  deleteUser () {
    //const userRef = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    this.usersRef.remove().then(function() {
      // User deleted.
      console.log("User deleted")
      router.push('/')
    }).catch(err => {
          this.error = err.message
      // An error happened.
      console.log("User NOT deleted")
    });
  }
};
</script>
```

Someone can help? Account is still, and cant remove. Zero info in console.

Comment: What exactly do you want to remove? A user existing in Firebase authentication database or a Firestore document representing a user?

Comment: A user existing in Firebase authentication

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete a user existing in Firebase authentication you have two possibilities:

#### 1/ Using the JavaScript SDK (since your app is made with Vue.js)

You call the [`delete()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#delete) method, as follows:

```
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
user.delete()
.then(() => {
   //....
})
.catch(err => {
  if (err.code === "auth/requires-recent-login") {
     //Re-authenticate the user and call again the Vue.js method
  } else {
     //....
  }
})
```

Note however, that this method "requires the user to have recently signed in. If this requirement isn't met, ask the user to authenticate again and then call `firebase.User.reauthenticateWithCredential`". An error with the `auth/requires-recent-login` code is "thrown if the user's last sign-in time does not meet the security threshold".

So, **only the logged-in user can call this method from a front-end**, in order to delete his/her own account.

#### 2/ Using the Admin SDK

You can use the Admin SDK's [`deleteUser()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#deleteuser) method, for example within a Cloud Function.

In this case, there is no need to have the user logged-in since this is executed in the back-end and it is therefore possible to delete any user. For example, you could have a Callable Cloud Function triggered by an admin user.

Comment: @polko Hi, did you have the opportunity to look at the proposed solution?